# Identity Server 4 multiple user resources

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I want to authenticate users at Identity server 4. I want to create a single instance of identity server that handles requests from many different applications that have users at different databases. For example:

```
App 1 -> users at database A
App 2 -> users at database A
App 3 -> users at database B
App 4 -> users at database C
```

Should I load all users from all databases (A,B,C) to identity server together and validate all apps against all users? What if identical usernames exists in more than one database?

is it possible to add scope at the user in order to filter the users that are going to be validated according to application-user scope?

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years late but one option, assuming the login flows are all using the `AccountController` for authentication and not the `ExternalController`, is to create your own `UserStore` that implements the `ValidateCredentials`, `FindBySubjectId`, and `FindByUsername` methods.  In that class you would have the various **DbContext** passed in via Dependency Injection for use by the three functions mentioned above.  Then, when you call any of the Find or Validate functions you pass in the regular parameters (i.e. username/password for validate, username for find by user, and subject id for find by subject) as well as the `clientId`.  Within the `AccountController`, where you'd be calling these functions, you can get the `clientId` from the context via `_interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl)?.Client.ClientId` where the `_interaction` object is a reference to the `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider`.  With all those values you can then have a check in the validate and find by methods that first checks the `clientId` and then executes the query against the database that is associated with that `clientId`.